# face skin cream

Tags: home-remedies, topical-cream-gel, face, blemishes, organic

I want to "fix" my face skin health look. I eat well but I don't see results on my face skin.Can I make my own cream for my skin?I don't want chemist things.I want to create "creams" to improve my face skin.Example can I use yogurt on my face? Things like this ,using fruits,vegetables I don't know what else but not chemist things.

Comment: "I don't want chemist things". You are aware that everything is a chemical and most medicaments are of biological origin and then produced industrially to be available in large amounts?

Comment: Also, please specify your question on certain dermatological issues or a certain health aspect. Fixing skin look is too broad in my opinion. Also, the answer is probably going to be "see the dermatologist of your choice" if it is a severe condition.

Comment: The question is very broad, but you can always [edit] it to ask specifically what would you like to improve - than we can suggest some ingredients that achieve this effect. For dermatological problems, as @Narusan said, you have to see a dermatologist.